# Skype for Business shows missed conversation notification while it does not list any

Tags: notifications, skype-for-business

For a long time, Skype for Business has been showing a “*You have 1 missed conversation(s)*” notification like this:

[image: Skype missed conversation notification]

However I don't have any missed conversation when I scroll the list of conversations below it.

How do I make this notification disappear?

Answer (score 1):

Click the “*View More in Outlook…*” link at the bottom of the screen to access the complete list of conversations.

Ensure all conversations are marked as read. After a moment, Skype for Business will remove the notification.